# How can I prevent aluminum window frames from heating up when they're in full sun?

Tags: insulation, windows

There is a room that has a window, the frame of the window is made of aluminum. This window is subjected to direct sunlight a long time of the day, which makes the aluminum get really hot, and start acting as a heat radiator and heating up the room pretty quickly.

What can I do to block the sun from heating up the window frame?

I tried putting some paper with adhesive tape, but it was not durable at all, even though there wasn't a lot of rain or water.

I prefer something DIY, if possible.

Comment: what color is it? can you paint it white?

Comment: @Steven 1.The current color is dark brown, 2. Painting it could be a solution, but seems a little bit harder, and it might require more work later if it wasn't so effective ..

Comment: Sometimes a single problem window like this is not the result of just direct sunlight?  Are others in direct sunlight not as hot?  It could be sun reflecting off of another corner of the siding and focusing a beam on the window as well.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas to try:

1. Paint the window frames white. This will reflect the light instead of absorbing it.  This might make quite a difference by itself
2. Cover the frames with XPS foam. On the inside you'd need to cover the foam with drywall or another fire barrier.
3. Plant a tree or bush near the window to help shade it
4. Replace the window with a vinyl window.  It's not as hard as it sounds and can definitely be DIY
5. Install an awning or trellis above the window (Thanks DA01)

Comment: Suggestion to add to the list: install an awning or trellis above the window.